# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface"

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

I'm having problem sharing a new project from eclipse, indingo, using http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

I've read through some issues on google, but none of them has solved my problem.

The message I get is following,

`Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".`

The stacktrace looks like this,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.client.PeekStatusCommand.execute(PeekStatusCommand.java:91)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.SVNWorkspaceRoot.peekResourceStatusFor(SVNWorkspaceRoot.java:296)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.wizards.sharing.SharingWizard.doesSVNDirectoryExist(SharingWizard.java:491)
at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.wizards.sharing.SharingWizard.addPages(SharingWizard.java:111)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage$1.selectionChanged(ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1725)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.setSelection(TableViewer.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:394)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.initializeWizardSelection(ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.java:257)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.createControl(ConfigureProjectWizardMainPage.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizard.openWizard(ConfigureProjectWizard.java:224)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ConfigureProjectWizard.shareProjects(ConfigureProjectWizard.java:124)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ConfigureProjectAction$1.run(ConfigureProjectAction.java:39)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction$3.run(TeamAction.java:266)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.run(TeamAction.java:263)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.ConfigureProjectAction.execute(ConfigureProjectAction.java:33)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.run(TeamAction.java:515)
at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.runWithEvent(TeamAction.java:549)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

And the session data,

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0_02
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean
```

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install Subclipse 1.6.x unless you have provided your own JavaHL binaries from Subversion 1.7.  Most Linux distros only provide SVN 1.6 and Subclipse can only provide the binaries for Windows.  See:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

Comment: Thanks Mark. Now it's working. I uninstalled subclipse 1.8.x, then I reinstalled libsvn-java and finally installed subclipse 1.6.x and made sure -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni was in my eclipse.ini bellow -vmargs.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if you installed the "Subclipse" plugin for eclipse, without also installing the accompanying "Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter". Make sure you select both of these options when installing Subclipse from the update site.